# re install Jdk1.6 in windows 7?

Tags: java, java-6

I have installed jdk1.6 in E: drive of windows 7.I developed a simple .java file and try to run it through the command prompt using "javac" but it says javac is not recognized as internal or external command.So i checked just by running java it runs fine .so I thought that i should uninstall that jdk and reinstallit but i am getting windows 1723 error

opened a control panel and tried to remove jdk from there but got this "Error 1723.There is problem with this Windows Installer package.A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

Comment: you have to add yout jdk/bin path into the PATH environment variable

Comment: i have already done that ,it is like path e:\jdk1.6\bin ,but still it is giving problem only on running javac command apart from that all command of bin directory running properly

Comment: have you closed all your command prompts (cmd) after change this configuration and open a new one?

Comment: yeah ,i did but still problem is with javac command only ,rest commands present in bin directory of jdk is running properly

Comment: as @andyb has pointed, it looks like you should have to reinstall the jdk

Answer (score 2):

to be able to run javac from the command line, you need to add the path to javac to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: i have already done that ,it is like  path e:\jdk1.6\bin ,but still it is giving problem on running javac command apart from that all command of bin directory running properly

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the **1723 error** describes a problem with the installer itself. I would follow the advice from [Microsoft Answers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/error-1723-there-is-a-problem-with-this-windows/05b35f6b-df35-4347-ac09-a6b1d07d9457) and [Oracle](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/error_1723.xml) to fix the installation. A correct install of Java should add the necessary entry on the Windows `PATH`. Make sure you open a *new* DOS (or Command) window after installation otherwise the amended PATH might not be picked up.

Comment: opened  a control panel and tried to remove jdk from there but got this "Error 1723.There is problem with this Windows Installer package.A DLL required for this install to complete could not be run.Contact your support personnel or package vendor"

Comment: Did you try the instructions from the Microsoft link in my answer to de-register and re-register the Windows Installer?

Answer (score 0):

Probably,you are facing the below issue: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2213081. You can use ccleaner to uninstall all the instance of jdk/jre.The issue is happening due to interrupting in installing/uninstalling.If ccleaer is not solving your problem registry cleaning is the only option as shown on the above link.

Comment: i have already done that ,it is like path e:\jdk1.6\bin ,but still it is giving problem only on running javac command apart from that all command of bin directory running properly

Answer (score 0):

You probably have java.exe on your \windows\system32 folder... And since this folder is on the path env var it got confused. Try to delete this/these java*.exe files from \windows\system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered a problem with Java error 1723 when you try to reinstall Java.
It may occur when you delete the Java directory by error

_ Go to your Microsoft Event Viewer you'll see one error line like this
[Event viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zftsi.jpg)

_ Then copy an Java bin directory from an other server to have back the lost dlls in the directory mentioned in the events viewer

_ finally reinstall Java

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have used Microsoft utility(fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) to resolve this error it saved me doing manual work and it is safe also :

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed